# Configuration of Signed APK giving an error "configuration is still incorrect"

Tags: java, android, signed-apk

After generate signed apk and configure it from android studio and an error "configuration is still incorrect" while i have enter the same password and key-store which i enter during apk generation.
Screen shot of Configuration is given below:
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8dh0.png)

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbYmO.png)

and when i press "OK" button i following dialog pop up "Configuration is still incorrect.Do you want to edit it"

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, remove your config completely from the settings and try Menu -> Build -> Generate Signed APK.
Generate a new key and use V1 (Jar Signature). Build Type: release.

Comment: i try this also but in my App there is Firebase Google and Facebook Authentication then that Authentication doesn't work (i means signin does not work)

Comment: See this link [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/). Create a Development Key Hash

Facebook uses the key hash to authenticate interactions between your app and the Facebook app. If you run apps that use Facebook Login, you need to add your Android development key hash to your Facebook developer profile.

For the version of your app that you release to you also need to generate and set a Release Key Hash.

On either OS X or Windows you can get a key has by generating it or by using the value returned by Settings.getApplicationSignature(Context).